# Adding a custom filter to jinja2 under pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid, jinja2

This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339899/jinja2-custom-filter-templateassertionerror-no-filter-named-format-number) but the accepted solution (given by the question poster himself) says that we can add the new filter to jinja2.filter.FILTER straightaway.

But in the [jinja2 documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters), it is advised that the filter be added to the environment.

I am developing an app under pyramid and need to define my custom filter and do the following.

```
from jinja2 import Environment

#Define a new filter
def GetBitValue(num,place):
    y = (num >> (place-1)) & 1
    return y

env = Environment()
env.filters['getbitvalue'] = GetBitValue
```

Where should this code fragment be placed?

I tried placing it in the views file but that obviously did not work.

If i place it in `__init__.py`, how do I make sure that jinja2 picks it up? I mean how do I send back the `env` to jinja2 settings under pyramid?

Comment: You shouldn't create a new environment but access the one pyramid uses.

Comment: From what I read in the pyramid docs jinja is not supported natively so please post the code how you are registering jinja as a renderer in pyramid.

Comment: Thanks for that pointer. I use pyramid_jinja2 for rendering jinja2 and they provide a function get_jinja2_environment(). Thanks the problem is solved

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you are using [`pyramid_jinja2`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_jinja2/en/latest/?awesome), you can use `pyramid_jinja2.get_jinja2_environment()` via the `configurator` instance to access the environment.

However, apparently you can also [register them via the pyramid config file](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_jinja2/en/latest/?awesome#jinja2-filters) without accessing the env directly:

```
[app:yourapp]
    # ... other stuff ...
    jinja2.filters =
        # ...
        getbitvalue = your_package.your_subpackage:GetBitValue
```

Comment: And what if I dont want to specify in config? Its not really a config thing, is it? It should be wired inside code. Config are meant for movable bits, which will be different for dev/prod stages.

Comment: Some additions:
config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
config.commit() # you might that one here 
jinjaEnv = config.get_jinja2_environment()

Answer (score 6):

For completeness this would be how you register the filter in code.

```
# __init__.py
def main(global_config, **settings):
    #....
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
    config.commit() # this is needed or you will get None back on the next line
    jinja2_env = config.get_jinja2_environment()
    jinja2_env.filters['getbitvalue'] = GetBitValue
```

Comment: This one is great!

Comment: This helps me a lot.